# Snort output auto generated FILE's names

Tags: snort

I’m using snort’s configuration:

`output alert_csv: alert.csv timestamp,sig_id,dst`

But everytime that Snort finishes, I can see a file named :

`alert.csv`

Instead of having a timestamp after the name :

`alert.csv.<timestamp>`

as other snort logs...

Hope to find a solution, Thanks.